# Send Email WIth Gmail Host And Port

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I want to send email with Gmail but I am getting the following exception

> *A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
>   [2a00:1450:400c:c05::6d]:465*

Do you have an idea how to resolve it ?

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("test@yahoo.com");
msg.To.Add("test@yahoo.com");
msg.Subject = this.txtSubject.Text;
msg.Body = this.txtBody.Text;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.Port = 465;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: See this, different but slightly similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717393/a-socket-operation-was-attempted-to-an-unreachable-network-in-python-httplib . Also are you using a proxy and how are you verifying the credentials?

Comment: I am verifying the credentials in web.config

Comment: Just try not using the web.config and putting it all in the C# code, just to confirm it makes no difference. Also, GMAIL some times requires you log on to your email account where there will be a pop up waiting asking you to verify you want to send email from this location.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem might be that my the machine I am  running this script on cannot reach the destination IP address , as it doesn't have a network route configured from one to the other ?

Comment: Yes, this is why I asked about a proxy. The message is clear - "unreachable network". Are you saying the computer in question is not online?

Comment: He is online but it has some permissions which I don't know about.

Comment: It appears the issue may not be a programming issue but an environment issue. Does it work from a different location?

Comment: Also, it appears you're using GMAIL to send email from Yahoo! ? Is that correct?

Comment: I edited this to send from gmail but the same exception again. I will try this on machine that I am sure it has full permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
NetworkCredential basicCredential = 
    new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 

smtpClient.Host = "mail.mydomain.com";
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;
```

(adopted from [How can I make SMTP authenticated in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298363/how-can-i-make-smtp-authenticated-in-c-sharp))

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using System.Net;

using System.Net.Mail;

 var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
 var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@test.com", "To Name");
 const string fromPassword = "fromPass";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

 var smtp = new SmtpClient
       {
           Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
           Port = 587,
           EnableSsl = true,
           DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
           UseDefaultCredentials = false,
           Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
       };
  using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                 {
                     Subject = subject,
                     Body = body
                 })
   {
smtp.Send(message);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like this:

With these Usings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

And this button event

```
 private void sendmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("blabla@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("mom@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "something";
            mail.Body = "text that is in the mail";
//for attachements
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(str);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
//end attachement

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential"username from gmail", "password from gmail");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("Mail Send");
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```